# Find a locus of a centroid point of a triangle.

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, circles, locus

When doing another geometry proof, I have this problem:
Let $A$ is the point outside the circle $(O;R)$ such that $OA=2R$. The line $d$ goes through $A$ and cut the circle at $2$ distinct points $E$ and $F$. What is the locus of the centroid point of the triangle $OEF$?

I used Geogebra to draw the trace of this centroid, it's an arc of a circle but i can't find out which point is the center.

Comment: At a glance, it appears that the centre $Q$ is the point on $OA$ such that $3OQ = OA$. That might help you investigate further.

Comment: Another hint: the problem specifies that $E$ and $F$ are distinct, but it is helpful to take the limiting case where $E=F$, i.e., $d$ is tangent to the circle.

Answer (score 2):

Assume $O$ is origin. Let $M$ be the midpoint of all chords $EF$. $\angle OMA = 90$. $M$ lies on arc of circle of diameter $OA$.

The centroid $G$, of $\triangle OEF$ lies two-thirds away from $O$ along $OM$.

[image]

Find $B$ on $OA$ so that $GB\parallel MA$. Clearly $\triangle OGB \sim \triangle OMA$. So $B$ lies two-thirds away from $O$ along $OA$.
$$B=\frac{2A}{3}$$

Hence $G$ lies on the circle whose diameter is $OB$. Its center $C$ is midpoint of $OB$.

$$C=\frac{O+B}{2}=\frac{A}{3}$$

Thus $C$ is $2R/3$ away from $O$ along $OA$.

Comment: In the last line, $2R/3$ should be $R/3$. Also, typesetting hint: you can use `\parallel` for $\parallel$.

Comment: @Theophile please notice the final result is in terms of radius R. 2R/3 is same as OA/3 as in your comment under the post. In the figure, I try to show B, C trisect OA.

Comment: Oh, I see. I read it as $1/3$ of the way towards $A$, but indeed it is $2R/3$. My typesetting hint still stands though. ;)

Comment: @Théophile Hint taken :)